# Unexpected behavior with ArrayObserver on DS.hasMany Relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use `DS.hasMany.addArrayObserver` to monitor when new elements are inserted (either created client side or loaded from the server).

However, the arguments passed to the `arrayWillChange` and `arrayDidChange` callbacks show inconsistent behavior between observing changes to a "plain" `Ember.A` vs a `DS.hasMany` relationship.

For the `Ember.A` array, the proper `addCount` and `removeCount` are passed, but with the `DS.hasMany` the `removeCount` is always equal to the old length of the array and `addCount` is always equal to the new length of the array.

In other words, it looks like the `DS.hasMany` "array" is emptied and all new records are added every time.  I have two questions:

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. If so, what is the best way to monitor just added/removed elements on a `DS.hasMany` relationship?

I have set up a demo of the behavior:  [DEMO](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hozononusu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

EDIT:

I have also opened an issue on the ember-data github: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2981

EDIT 2:

This looks like it is expected behavior.  Ember-data is generating a new array by `filter`ing out deleted items and `concat`ing new items.  This happens in `flushCanonical`:  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/339b79aa3ea82e9be1a8f39db36ec1133d0b65a2/packages/ember-data/lib/system/many-array.js#L67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, in a somewhat non-intuitive way.  Instead of adding an `ArrayObserver` directly to the model's `HasMany` relationship, I am using `DS.Store.filter()` to get the relevant records, and using `addArrayObserver` to the results.

Relevant code:

```
var collection = this.store.filter('child', function(record){ return record.get('parent.id') === "1"; });
collection.then(function(records){
    records.addArrayObserver({
          arrayWillChange: function(obj, start, removeCount, addCount) {
            console.log("Filter", start, removeCount, addCount);
          },
          arrayDidChange: Ember.K
        });     
});
```

[DEMO](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jiwapikama/1/edit?html,js,console,output)